# Can this be shortened / streamlined in any way?

Tags: python, parsing, variables, stdout, readlines

I'm currently trying to learn Python and might still be doing things in too many steps/too bulky a way.

I got the following lines of code in one of my small programs and have been wondering if I could make it a bit more efficient?

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo -e "MAIN\nnotifications\nsmtp\nstatus$" | confd-client.plx -batch')
orglines = stdout.readlines()
smtpstatus = int(orglines[20])
if smtpstatus == 1:
     do something
else:
     do something else
```

Example output from stdout looks as this:

```
['Available modes: MAIN OBJS RAW WIZARD.\n', 'Type mode name to switch mode.\n', "Typing 'help' will always give some help.\n", 'device_info$\n', 'limiting$\n', 'overlay@\n', 'reboot_reason%\n', 'recipients@\n', 'sender$\n', 'smtp\n', 'authentication$\n', 'password$\n', 'port$\n', 'server$\n', 'status$\n', 'tls$\n', 'username$\n', '1\n']
```

Basically, could I get the variable smtpstatus to be populated in a more efficient way from the stdout output here? I'm not sure if the fact that I have to convert it to an integer makes it a bit more complicated?

The 'field number' can vary from time to time, for this particular value it is 20 as you can see from the code snippet above.

Thanks in advance, Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Not by much anyway. Conversion to an `int` is a bit inefficient yes, since it has an exception handling overhead... but you could just compare `smtpstatus == "1\n"` as in comparing those two strings. But it wouldn't make that much of a difference. You could also consider to only read `stdout` up to the 20th line, if you don't need the rest. That's probably the biggest slowdown.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's how you do that greying out. @tim

Comment: You're welcome. Check out [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), it's great what you can do here.

Comment: Tim,

Thanks for your feedback, really appreciated. 

Could you please extend a bit on how to just read 'stdout' up to the 20th line? I had troubles dealing with it on a 'per line basis' initially - that's why I use 'stdout.readlines()' instead of 'stdout.read()' actually.

Comment: Tim,

I think I got it a bit more streamlined thanks to your initial reply.

Now I'm doing the following:
    `orglines = stdout.readlines()
    if orglines[20] == "1\n":`

That makes it one less variable and one `int` conversion less.

Thanks for putting me on the right track! ;)

Comment: Daniel - sorry to have gotten the name wrong. I'm still getting used to reading the forum format I guess...